# Want to convert my existing site to mobile. Solution may be phonegap

Tags: ios, flash, mobile, cordova

I have developed a web site with Drupal and used PHP/jQuery/Ajax (jQuery)/CSS/HTML/Flash/Drupal module; for the web server I used Apache.

I want to run the same site as a mobile web site. I know I have to change the formatting of the pages for mobile devices. I did some research and found PhoneGap is the better solution. As it is compatible with all mobile devices like Blackberry, iPhone, iPad, Android.

I also know I have to change my Flash plugin to a Javascript plugin etc. I do not have Mac OS X and I want to start working on Phonegap on a Windows machine and upload the files on a Linux-based hosting system. I do not have any clue how to start learning Phonegap and how to install Phonegap on a Windows 7 client. If anybody has tools to suggest then please help. I am also willing to attend a good online training or read books for this.

Answer (score 2):

The best place to start is the [getting started guides](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html). You should really figure out what platform you want to develop for before jumping into Phonegap but before you even do any of that let me clarify something.

Phonegap is an API that lets you make Hybrid apps -- essentially these are applications on a mobile device that allow you to develop in HTML/CSS/JS but at the same time still give you access to a lot of the native features including Accelerometer, Camera, Location, etc. If your application/website doesn't use any of those, then you might not need to go through all this hassle.

You said you are developing just a website. If you want to run a mobile version of your website, you can consider making a sub-domain and making a website that is dedicated only for mobile users (there are ways to detect the browser someone is viewing your website with so you can direct them to the mobile version if they are using a mobile browsers). There are also a lot of sites that can help mobilize your website for you -- [here](https://www.uppsite.com/) is one I found a while ago but never had a chance to try although I think it's a lot better if you just develop your own. Still you can take a look if it helps you.

And just an FYI, simply developing a mobile version of your website is a lot simpler because you do it once and it should work across browsers. Sure you might have to make some adjustments for specific browsers, but its the same for developing for different devices. Phonegap does have cross-platform functionality but it still requires you to handle the code differently among different devices (notice how there is an android sdk, an ios sdk, etc...) Hope this helps.

Comment: What i understand from above. I have to developed same site in same tool css/html/ajax/jquerymobile and make the interface for mobile user.when user connect with mobile i will redirect to the user to my mobile site. I have the flash base graph in my site. How i will overcome this for mobile user. As far as my knowledge the flash  graph is not support on iphone etc.... PHONEGAP (apache cordova) will not installed on window 7 for developed ios application am i right. ...

Comment: I'm sorry I don't completely understand what you mean by "flash graph" is this a graph you are making via Adobe flash? And as for your second question, PhoneGap can be installed on Windows 7 and I believe they do have an iOS SDK that allows you to develop for it and instructions [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS)

Comment: Yes i make the graph from adobe flash on my site. Do you recommend any book or site for developed the application with css/html/ajax for mobile (andriod and ipad iphone).Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Unfortunately my knowledge of Flash isn't that strong. Flash is dying and people are starting to look towards HTML5/CSS3 nowadays for animations (Adobe Edge is the new flash). I'll try to see if I come across any but not entirely sure.